# How to extract csv separated values in rows in SQL?

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I was wondering how one can extract the following information in SQL for example:

```
ID Hobbies
1  Swimming; Dancing; Zumba
2  Swimming; Eating; Baseball
3  Hockey; Polo; Fishing
```

Now I simply want for example the sport with the lowest first letter in alphabetical order. In this case it would be:

```
ID Hobbies (min)
1  Dancing
2  Baseball
3  Fishing
```

A more general question maybe, is it possible to "revert" the process of XML row concatenation?

PS: I am currently using SQL Server 2014 and the hobbies are not sorted.

Code for creating the testing table

```
CREATE TABLE TestTable
    ([ID] INT, [Hobbies] varchar(MAX))
;

INSERT INTO TestTable
    ([ID], [Hobbies])
VALUES
    (1, 'Swimming; Dancing; Zumba'),
    (2, 'Swimming; Eating; Baseball'),
    (3, 'Hockey; Polo; Fishing')
;
```

Thanks!

Comment: please look up 3NF ....

Answer (score 0):

This will expand your list. You can then easily add a group by and min(hobby) or really do whwatever you like easily in this form.

```
WITH CTE_XML
AS
(
    SELECT  ID,
            xml_hobbies = CAST('<t>' + REPLACE(hobbies,'; ','</t><t>') + '</t>' AS XML)
    FROM testTable
)

SELECT  ID,
        hobby = t.value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)')
FROM CTE_XML
CROSS APPLY xml_hobbies.nodes('t') CA(t)
```

Results:

```
ID          hobby
----------- -------------
1           Swimming
1           Dancing
1           Zumba
2           Swimming
2           Eating
2           Baseball
3           Hockey
3           Polo
3           Fishing
```